Get AWS cloudwatch Log Insight with timeseries and dynamic filter by grouping the result
fields @timestamp, @message, errorData.msg.text
| filter !isblank(errorData.msg.text)
| parse @message "[*]" as errorData
| stats sum(1) as TotalCount by errorData.msg.text, bin(15m)

On the x-axis, I want to show a time series with a 15-minute interval, and on the y-axis, it should show the count. Different lines should represent different errorData.msg.text. This is because when I click on errorData.msg.text, it should only show the line corresponding to that errorData.msg.text
With above query I am not getting expected result
